# Anonymous struct inside loop

Tags: c++, gcc, g++

The code below compiles fine with g++

```
#include <iostream>
using namespace std; 

int main() 
{
    for (struct { int i; double j; } x = {0,0};  x.i < 10; ++x.i, x.j+=.1)
    {
        std::cout << x.i << " " << x.j << '\n';
    }
}
```

But with MSVC2005 I get errors

```
error C2332: 'struct' : missing tag name
error C2143: syntax error : missing ')' before '{'
warning C4094: untagged 'struct' declared no symbols
error C2059: syntax error : 'empty declaration'
error C2143: syntax error : missing ';' before ')'
error C2143: syntax error : missing ';' before ')'
error C2065: 'x' : undeclared identifier
error C2059: syntax error : '{'
error C2143: syntax error : missing ';' before '{'
error C2143: syntax error : missing ';' before '}'
error C2228: left of '.i' must have class/struct/union
1>        type is ''unknown-type''
error C2228: left of '.i' must have class/struct/union
1>        type is ''unknown-type''
error C2228: left of '.j' must have class/struct/union
1>        type is ''unknown-type''
error C2059: syntax error : ')'
error C2143: syntax error : missing ';' before '{'
error C2228: left of '.i' must have class/struct/union
1>        type is ''unknown-type''
error C2228: left of '.j' must have class/struct/union
1>        type is ''unknown-type''
```

I want to know if anonymous struct inside loops are an "extension" or a language feature and MSC2005 is missing it?

Comment: I'm fairly sure it is standard. clang++ accepts it with `-pedantic-errors`.

Comment: Why do you want to do such a thing to begin with?!

Comment: Still [does not compile on VS2012](http://rise4fun.com/Vcpp/WMz). Probably a gcc extension - I'm not sure though.

Comment: This is just VC++ being VC++. Should work just fine.

Comment: @Synxis: It is NOT an extension. It is Standard C++.

Comment: @Nawaz Ok, I didn't know before now^^.

Answer (score 7, accepted):

It's a [bug in msvc](http://connect.microsoft.com/VisualStudio/feedback/details/624410/visual-c-compiler-fails-to-parse-a-for-init-statement-that-starts-with-a-class-specifier). Unfortunately, it is not high in their priority list.

Comment: @stardust_: I [reported it again](https://connect.microsoft.com/VisualStudio/feedback/details/782926/class-declaration-fails-in-for-loop).